# Accessing a class from an externally loaded Flex SWF

Tags: apache-flex

Using Flex 4, I have created an SWF that has the following code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import com.Index ;

        protected function start(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            this.addElement (new Index());
        }
    ]]>
```

What I am trying to do is load the SWF into another SWF and access this class. The problem is the Flex class Main is what is recognized by the loading SWF. I have tried accessing its children(elements), but the added item is not there.

My ultimate goal is to load an SWF that has an object that can interact with the loading SWF.

lee

Addition:

Thanks for your addition. The code is working now, but it only access the Flex class created by the MXML. Here is the complete MXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
           width="1000"
           height="700"
           creationComplete="start(event)"
           >
```

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import Test;

        protected function start(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            this.addElement(new Test ());
        }
    ]]>
```

To try and extract the class Test, I did the following:

```
var MainC:Class = L.contentLoaderInfo .applicationDomain .getDefinition ("Main.Test") as Class;
        var O:Object = new MainC();
```

This returns 'Error #1065: Variable Test is not defined.'

I get the same result if I use ...getDefinition("Test").

If I use ....getDefinition("Main"), it works fine. But I cannot seem to reach into the class it creates to extract anything.

lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to go is to have that swf as a library (swc) and link it to your project. That way you could achieve strong typing, and access the underlying classes.

If you don't have access to neither the library release of the swf object, nor it's source to build the swc library yourserlf, you can still use the external classes, but not with strong typing:

```
var ExtIndex : Class = loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefintiion("Index");
var instance : Object = new ExtIndex();
this.addElement(instance);
```

so you must define your `instance` as Object.

Although, in case the `Index` class in your swf implements an `interface` that you know of (you have it in your project), like `I_Index`, you can use it instead of `Object`:

```
var instance : I_Index = new ExtIndex();
this.addElement(instance);
```

You might also find [this article useful](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=performance_07.html) in deciding which way to go.

**Update 1**

Declaring the `loader` in Flex:

```
var loader: flash.display.Loader;
[...]
var ExtIndex: Class = loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.
    getDefinition("your.package.Index") as Class;
```

In case you have your `Index` class in a package (other than the default), you should specify it in its name. The code above searches for the `Index` class inside the `your/package` package.

**API Docs** for `getDefinition`:

> Gets a public definition from the
>   specified application domain. The
>   definition can be that of a class, a
>   namespace, or a function.

**Parameters:**
`name` The name of the definition.
**Returns**: The object associated with the definition.
**Throws**: `ReferenceError` - No public definition exists with the specified name.

Language Version: 3.0
Player Version: Flash 9, AIR 1.0

**Update 2**
To make the `Test` class defined in your external application accessible from other flex applications by loading the swf that contains it, you must have a variable declared with that type inside your swf's main application. Otherwise that class won't be compiled into the swf (to save the size of it).
 Flex only compiles classes actually in use into the swf, so it's not enough to just import a class.
 In the main application of your swf you should declare:

```
var _tmp:Index;
```

This makes sure that the `Index` class will be compiled into your swf, and you can access it from an other application which loads that swf.

**Update 3**
You can check out how this works at [this link](http://tordai.rekaszeru.ro/extswf/). The source code is included too.

Since there are two projects, in the [src] folder you can see the test's source, and in the [source path src] folder the source of the externally loaded swf file. 
If you download the whole project, make sure that you separate the two projects.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your comment. However, I get an error on the var ExtIndex : Class... line that says you cannot turn an object into a class. When I trace it out, it is getting the SystemManager, not the INdex class.

Comment: Hello,  I tried it again. However, the Loader class i saying getDefinition is not a valid call. Funny thing...WHen I use Loader.ContentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain in a MovieClip, it works fine, but when I try it in Flex, I can only get to Loader.contentLoaderInfo There is no applicationDomain, yet is errors out that the problem is with getDefinition. lee

Comment: see my update, and if you have problems please paste some stack traces

Comment: Hello, thanks for all your help. I have updated my post with some new info.

Comment: You should use `"Main.Test"` if your `Test` class is inside a package named `Main`! Please see my update for how to eliminate the `Variable not defined` error.

Comment: Hello, thanks again for your continued help. However, that didn't work either. Is it possible there is something about Flex 4 that is preventing this from happening? I've done lots of searching, and everything you have said matches-up with the things I've read. Do you believe there might be a solution that utilizes SWFLoader?

Comment: no, i've tested it with flex4 spark, and works. i'll share my test projects in a couple of minutes, to have it as a reference, i just need to comment my code for better understanding. i'll update the answer with the link.

Comment: Hello, thanks. Could you take a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752154/spark-textflow-size

Comment: In my previous comment i said no to "Is it possible there is something about Flex 4 that is preventing this from happening?". I've worked with SWFLoader on the other hand, so for "Do you believe there might be a solution that utilizes SWFLoader?" the answer is yes. Please see my update for a working sample.